# Ruby, gaps in time for array of times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have query (for a MongoDB database) which returns objects which have been mapreduced, the objects are reported every 15 minutes, but the issue is that if say we have a critical error in one of servers that period of time will be unaccounted for.

Take this array as an example:

```
[
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 19:00:00 UTC, :count=>318},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 19:15:00 UTC, :count=>308},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 19:30:00 UTC, :count=>222},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 19:45:00 UTC, :count=>215},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 20:00:00 UTC, :count=>166},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 21:15:00 UTC, :count=>149},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 21:30:00 UTC, :count=>145},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 21:45:00 UTC, :count=>107},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 22:00:00 UTC, :count=>137},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 22:15:00 UTC, :count=>135},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 22:30:00 UTC, :count=>191},
  {:timestamp=>2011-09-26 22:45:00 UTC, :count=>235}
]
```

You'll notice that the times are missing for the time range:

```
{:timestamp=>2011-09-26 20:15:00 UTC},
{:timestamp=>2011-09-26 20:30:00 UTC},
{:timestamp=>2011-09-26 20:45:00 UTC},
{:timestamp=>2011-09-26 21:00:00 UTC}
```

How can I take the top as the input and deduce that those would be the missing rows? The time increments will always be 15 minutes, and its actually a real date object not a string like that.

I just can't picture how to iterate over this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to order the array by the time stamp, and then do something like the following:

```
missing_times = []
reports.each_with_index do |report, index|
  if reports[index + 1]
    if report.timestamp.advance(minutes: 15) < report[index + 1].timestamp
      i = 0
      while(report.timestamp.advance(minutes: 15*i) < report[index+1].timestamp)
        missing_times << report.timestamp.advance(minutes: 15*i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I had previously written similar code to find half hour gaps in a series of appointments

Although it may look like my solution will loop multiple times over the 15 minute increments between reports.first and reports.last, it will actually loop only once over all available increments between reports.first and reports.last

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing this, on the line `if report[:timestamp].advance(minutes: 15) < report[index + 1][:timestamp]` the `report[index + 1]` right after the less than is nil? and when I change it to `reports[index + 1]` which is what I thought it would be the look goes for ever. thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing multiple loops within loops, it'd be more efficient with large data sets if you create an array of the total timespan in 15 minute increments, and just compare against your report set and remove any matches.

```
start_time = report.first
span = ((report.last - start_time)/60/15).to_i   # this gives the number of 15min blocks
test_array = []
span.times do |i|
  test_array << start_time + i*15.minutes
end
report.each do |r|
  test_array.delete(r)   # or in your case, r.timestamp
end
```

I think it works, but couldn't think of a good way to make a reference table of timestamps, so I hacked my way up there.

Comment: My answer only loops when there is a gap greater than 15 minutes, if there are no gaps, my solution only iterates once over the array.  Also, my array won't loop over all possible times, only the ones to fill the gap.  Your solution will always have 2 loops, one to load up the time span, the other to loop over all the elements.  When there are no gaps, your solution will loop twice over all the elements.  My worst case scenario will always loop once over all available increments, equal to your `span.times` loop

Comment: Additionally, test_array.delete iterates over the array itself to find the element to delete, see the code: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M000255.html, so your code is O(n^2), as every time you call delete, you potentially loop over the whole array

Answer (score 0):

Simply start at the first timestamp, then increment by 15 minutes, verify that that entry exists, and keep going until you reach the last timestamp.